# Can I get the Vim Ctrlp plugin to ignore a specific folder in one project?

Tags: vim

The [Vim Ctrlp plugin](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) has a way to globally ignore certain folder names. Eg:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/]\.(git|hg|svn)$'
```

However, I have an ignore rule that's specific to one project. I would like something more like a `.gitignore` file.

Is there a way to ignore a specific folder in a specific project without modifying my global configuration?

Comment: Did you try the plugin's issue tracker?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Use a custom listing command

Ctrlp lets you tell it what command to use to get a list of files in the folder. So if you wanted to exclude anything named `beets.txt`, you could do:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f | grep -v "beets.txt"'
```

That's global, but it starts to point toward the answer: supply your own shell command.

Even better, Ctrlp lets you supply multiple shell commands with markers, meaning "if you see this marker in the root directory, use this command."

I found this in `:help ctrlp`, and modified slightly based on the author's comment on an issue.

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = {
  \ 'types': {
    \ 1: ['.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files --cached --exclude-standard --others'],
    \ 2: ['.hg', 'hg --cwd %s locate -I .'],
    \ },
  \ 'fallback': 'find %s -type f'
  \ }
```

This means: "If you see `.git` in the folder, use `git ls-files...`. Otherwise, if you see `.hg`, use `hg --cwd...`, otherwise use a regular `find`."

So, **to ignore a specific folder in one project, devise a command that will ignore that folder, then place a unique marker in that project to let Ctrlp that you want to use your special command here**.

(In my case, I actually wanted to ignore files that were in `.gitignore`, so the `git ls-files` command above works for me.)

Comment: git -C %s ls-files --cached --exclude-standard --others should work for git.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the Silver Searcher backend for CtrlP (which is far faster), just add an `.agignore` file to your project directory in the same format as a `.gitignore`:

```
.git/
.hg/
.svn/
```

Alternatively, keep a global `~/.agignore` file.

Add the Silver Searcher as the backend with this in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --hidden -g ""'
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  To add another data point: I adapted this  `if executable("ag")
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor --depth 8 -g ""'
endif
`.  The depth limit is useful for if I accidentally hit ctrl-p while editing a file in my home folder.  I found that the hidden flag would include files in .git/

Answer (score 6):

### Specifies intentionally untracked files in a file

To solve this with a file like `.gitignore` (based in the Nathan grep solution), I created a file named `.ctrlpignore` and put the patterns that should be ignored, separated by lines:

```
node_modules/
\.log$
...
```

And my ctrlp configuration:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'find %s -type f | grep -v "`cat .ctrlpignore`"'
```

Maybe the `.gitignore` itself can be used to ignore the files in ctrlp, not needing to create a new file to do almost the same thing.

Comment: I added this snippet but it breaks the overal ctrlp behavior, if I type orderscontroller it finds only _spec files, no actual orders_controller.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wagner Andrade](https://superuser.com/a/900794/304204) said, using a seperate `.ctrlpignore` would be a good idea.

A more robust and convenient vim setting is like this:

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'cd %s;
  \ commonfilter="\.(jpg|bmp|png|jar|7z|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz)$";
  \ if [ ! -r ".ctrlpignore" ]; then
  \   find . -type f | grep -Evi "$commonfilter";
  \ else
  \   find . -type f | grep -vF "$(cat .ctrlpignore)" | grep -Evi "$commonfilter";
  \ fi'
```

`.ctrlpignore` can be put in any dir that would be recognized as a root dir by ctrlp. Here is an example, every line is starting with `./`

`vim ~/.ctrlpignore`

```
./Desktop
./R
./.vim
./.local/lib
.....
```

Note:

1. `grep -F` will interpret pattern, ex. './.tmp', as a fixed string if you don't want your './ptmp' be filtered out. There are still some trivial bugs: './.tmp' will also filter out './.tmp2'. Forget it, I don't like `\.`
2. `g:ctrlp_custom_ignore` will be ignored if `g:ctrlp_user_command` is set. Those could be done in a more complex `g:ctrlp_user_command`
3. white-list instead of black-list is also possible. More convenient if implemented in a seperate script

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ag`](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), I was able to setup a system like:

```
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = '
      \ filter="jpg|bmp|png|jar|7z|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz";
      \ if [ -f "bsconfig.json" ]; then
      \   subfilter="lib"
      \   filter="$filter|$subfilter"
      \ fi;
      \ if [ -f "Cargo.toml" ]; then
      \   subfilter="target"
      \   filter="$filter|$subfilter"
      \ fi;
      \ if [ -f "elm.json" ]; then
      \   subfilter="elm-stuff"
      \   filter="$filter|$subfilter"
      \ fi;
      \ if [ -f "package.json" ]; then
      \   subfilter="node_modules|*.min.js"
      \   filter="$filter|$subfilter"
      \ fi;
      \ ag %s -l --nocolor -g "" --ignore "\.($filter)$"
      \ '
```

which allows you to mark certain files to ignore based on files found in the directory you launch vim from. For example, in a JS project with `package.json`, we want to ignore both `node_modules` and `*.min.js`, and so on. This worked well for me because I didn't want to duplicate the same `.agignore` in every JS project, and I want to support handling multiple patterns, like an Elm and JS project in the same directory.